# Convert Google doc to Word document with reduced oAuth scopes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I need to convert the active Google document into a Word document within a specific folder using the below oAuth scopes.

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly" 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
```

This is my implemented script.

```
 function convertGoogleDocToWordDoc() {

  var rootFolder = findFolderOrFile("MyTest",'application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
  if(rootFolder!= null){
      folderID = rootFolder;
  }
  else{
    var rFolder = {
      title: "MyTest",
      mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    };
    
    var folder = Drive.Files.insert(rFolder);
    folderID = folder.getId();
  }

  var documentObject = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();  
  var ext = ".docx";

  // Fetch the docx blob
  var blb = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" + documentObject.getId()+ "&exportFormat=docx", 
    {
      headers : {
        Authorization : 'Bearer '+token
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
      }).getBlob();

  var filename = documentObject.getName();
  var name = ~filename.indexOf(ext) ? filename : filename + ext;

  var file = {
    title: name,
    mimetype :'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    parents: [{'id':folderID}]
  }

  var file = Drive.Files.insert(file,blb);

  return file.getId();

}
```

This creates a Word document in the correct format within the "MyTest" folder only when I use the `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"` oAuth scope.

How should I modify this script to create the Word document using the `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentlyonly"` scope ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend switching to google drive v3 https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create

Comment: When I tested your script with the scopes of `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"`, no error occurs. The DOCX file converted from Google Document is put to the folder. So, when you ran your script, can I ask you about the error message?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, it doesn't give errors, but the creating .docx file is corrupted. Try opening the created .docx file.

Comment: @DaImTo I tried to use the drive/api/v3 export as in this article https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/8d639542577a594f6104b7f6fb753064. But it needs "auth/drive" scope to work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer by guessing your situation. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

For my following asking,

> When I tested your script with the scopes of `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"`, no error occurs. The DOCX file converted from Google Document is put to the folder. So, when you ran your script, can I ask you about the error message?

I got the following reply,

> Yes, it doesn't give errors, but the creating .docx file is corrupted. Try opening the created .docx file.

From your reply and your showing script, I thought that your current situation might be related to your Google Document of `var documentObject = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()` and the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`.

If your Google Document of `var documentObject = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()` is not created by the same client with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`, the Google Document cannot be obtained. By this, I thought that in the case of your script, your this situation `it doesn't give errors, but the creating .docx file is corrupted.` might occur.

But, this is just my guess. So, in order to confirm my guess, please test the following modified script using your Google Apps Script project which has your showing script.

#### Sample script

```js
function sample() {
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  // 1. Create new Google Document using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
  var doc = Drive.Files.insert({ title: "sampleDocument", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS }, Utilities.newBlob("sample text", MimeType.HTML));

  // 2. Export Google Document as DOCX.
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    `https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=${doc.id}&exportFormat=docx`,
    { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token } }
  ).getBlob();
  Drive.Files.insert({ title: "convertedDOC.docx" }, blob);
}
```

- When you copy and paste this script to your Google Apps Script project which has your showing script, this script can be run with the scopes of `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"`.
- When you run this script, a new Google Document is created and the created Google Document is exported as DOCX file. By this, you can see `sample text` in the exported DOCX file. This DOCX is not broken.
- When I tested this script with those scopes, I confirmed that the valid DOCX file can be exported.

## Workaround:

As a workaround for achieving your goal, I would like to propose using Web Apps as a wrapper API for exporting Google Document. Your current situation is as follows.

1. 3 scopes of `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"` are used.
2. Your active Google Document is not created by the client of this Google Apps Script project.

   - By this, an error like `it doesn't give errors, but the creating .docx file is corrupted.` occurs.
3. You want to export this Document using only these scopes.

### Usage:

#### 1. Create Google Apps Script for Web Apps.

In order to use Web Apps, please create a new Google Apps Script project. In this case, it is not required to modify `appsscript.json`.

#### 2. Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the created Google Apps Script project.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  const { documentId } = e.parameter;
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    `https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=${documentId}&exportFormat=docx`,
    { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }
  ).getBlob();
  var obj = Drive.Files.insert({ title: "convertedDOC.docx" }, blob);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(obj.id);
  
  // DriveApp.getFiles(); // This is used for automatically detecting the scope for exporting Document. But, from `Drive.Files.insert`, this might not be required to be used.
}
```

- In this case, the required scopes are automatically detected.

#### 3. Enable Drive API.

[Please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

#### 4. Deploy Web Apps.

The detailed information can be seen at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.

   - This is the importance of this workaround.
5. Please select **"Anyone"** for **"Who has access"**.

   - In your situation, I thought that this setting might be suitable.
   - In order to simply access to this Web Apps, I used this setting.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. Copy the URL of the Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
   - You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### 5. Testing.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Google Apps Script project with the scopes of `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"`. And, please set your Web Apps URL to `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

```js
function sample2() {
  var documentId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  var webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppsUrl + "?documentId=" + documentId);
  console.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

- When this script is run, this script requests with the document ID of the active Document. And, the active Google Document is exported as DOCX file by the Web Apps using those 3 scopes.

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Yes, your assumption is right. Your code works and creates a valid Word document file. But in my situation, I have to convert the **active** Google document into a Word document which is not created using the same client.

Comment: My project inserts a custom menu into Google docs, and the active document is the base of the other functionalities. I even thought to create a, exact copy of the active document and convert it to a Word docx. But I was unable to find a way.

Comment: @ApsSanj Thank you for replying. From your reply, I confirmed that my guess was correct. About your new issue, as a simple method, how about creating a new Document using my proposed script, and how about manually copying the contents of your active Document to the created Document? By this, you can use the created Document using those scopes. But, if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that too. Tried creating a new google document, in order to copy the active doc content to it, it seems we need to open the newly created doc,  var newDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newDocId); var body = newDoc.getBody();
In this line, I get error, as it needs 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents' scope for it.

Comment: @ApsSanj Thank you for replying. About `I tried that too. Tried creating a new google document, in order to copy the active doc content to it, it seems we need to open the newly created doc, var newDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newDocId); var body = newDoc.getBody(); In this line, I get error, as it needs 'googleapis.com/auth/documents' scope for it.`, I'm worried about this. So, I proposed to manually copy and paste. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. Manually coping is not a choice. May be I'll have to loose my scope to use "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"

Comment: @ApsSanj Thank you for replying. Can you give me a time a little? I prepare another workaround for achieving your goal.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Yes, sure. that will be great.

Comment: @ApsSanj Thank you for replying. Now, I proposed a workaround in my answer. Could you please confirm it? In this workaround, the scopes you don't want to use are used at Web Apps as the wrapper API. I thought that by this, your goal can be achieved. But, if this workaround was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I tried it with the exact steps as you mentioned. But when try to deploy the webApp, it requested for authorization and that prompt seek authorization for "See, edit, create and delete all of your google drive files" which I never wanted. When I click allow, and use that in my script, it execute well and create the .docx file.

Comment: @ApsSanj Thank you for replying. About `I tried it with the exact steps as you mentioned. But when try to deploy the webApp, it requested for authorization and that prompt seek authorization for "See, edit, create and delete all of your google drive files" which I never wanted. When I click allow, and use that in my script, it execute well and create the .docx file.`, this is my workaround.

Comment: @ApsSanj In this workaround, your script uses the specific scopes you want to use. And, at the Web Apps, Google Document is exported using the scope for exporting Google Document. So, Web Apps is used as the wrapper API. I deeply apologize that I proposed this workaround for achieving your goal. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I am new to Apps script. I learned about using web apps as the wrapper api from your answer. Really appreciate that.

Comment: @ApsSanj Thank you for replying. In your situation, in order to export the Google Document, it is required to change the scopes from your expected 3 scopes. So, I thought that as a workaround, when Web Apps is used as the wrapper API, your goal might be able to be used. I deeply apologize that I cannot propose a direct method for achieving your goal. This is due to my poor skill. About this, I have to apologize. I would like to study more and more.

Answer (score 0):

- I believe it is just not possible. You must use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents` as scope, otherwise instead of the document contents, a HTML string containing an Error (`Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.`) is returned by the `export` endpoint.
- According to the best practices in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads), I’d recommend for you to consider using Drive API v3 method [Files: export()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export).
- Running the method above on my end (without changes), the minimum OAuth scopes to properly save the document as Docx are:

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
  ]
```

Comment: I tried using Drive api/v3 earlier. But it needs below scopes to convert the Google doc correctly into a word docuement.
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly"
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"

Comment: @ApsSanj You'll need to implement a OAuth flow (or just pass the same Bearer token) and modify the OAuth scopes accordingly to the methods you are using in your script. To fetch the file from the Drive export endpoint as your script does, with `googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly` it just returns an HTML string (with `Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.` message) rather then the actual converted files. TLDR, you must modify your OAuth scopes to use this approach